# Pass authenticatication data from client while connecting to socket io server

Tags: node.js, go, socket.io

I need to pass authentication data from client while connecting to socket io server. The authenticated clients can only established connection to socket server. So my server is expecting an object like this, for which the equivalent nodejs socket client looks like this:

```
socket = io('localhost:3000', {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        token: "abcd",
      },
 });
```

While my server receives both values as `socket.handshake.auth.username` and `socket.handshake.auth.token`. Now I want to do the same in golang. I need to pass auth params equivalent to the above code. But couldn't find a way to do that. There are ways to pass query param here https://github.com/hesh915/go-socket.io-client but I didn't find any implementation to pass auth params. Is there any way I can pass authentication data from my socket client on golang to establish connection with my socket io server?

Comment: u wanna send params to ur nodeJS service or u wanna implement socketIO with Authentication in go?

Comment: The above code pass `auth` params to server which authenticate the client. I want the same client side functionality in golang to pass `auth` to my server side.

Comment: which go socketio implementation u are using? From what I know there isn't a version that supports the latest version of socketio

Comment: I'm using this go socket.io-client implementation https://github.com/hesh915/go-socket.io-client

Comment: note the latest update to this pkg is 7 years ago. Other packages for socketio implementation i golang only supports up to v2. Socketio is now v4.

Comment: Is there any other implementation in go compatible with 4.x version socket.io?

Comment: not that i Know of. You should stick to node if u want to use latest version of socketio